# Looking to construct a Regexp that finds 3 words separated by white space of different specific lengths in order

Tags: javascript, python, regex

Say for example we are given a string

`"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"`

How can I construct a Regexp that will find a block of 3 words separated by whitespace of specified length. Specifically lets say a word of length 5 followed by  3 and then 4 With the given string this would match to `"dolor sit amet"`.

Extremely grateful to anyone that can shed some light on this. Any solutions in any language you prefer are acceptable, I'm most just concerned of the actual Regexp that would accomplish this. Preferably would like JS or python though. Thank you!

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what you've attempted so far! Here's a handy regex cheatsheet for reference: http://web.mit.edu/hackl/www/lab/turkshop/slides/regex-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: 1) What should be of specified length: the whitespaces, the words or the whole match? 2) In what environment are you going to use your regex?

Comment: Are you looking for `\w{5}\s\w{3}\s\w{4}`? Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XAxFs/1). And if the words may only contain English letters (as opposed to any alphanumeric characters or underscore), use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case of a 5 letter word, 3 letter, and 4 letter word, you may use the regex pattern:

```regex
\b\w{5}\s\w{3}\s\w{4}\b
```

Sample script:

```js
var input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
var result = input.match(/\b\w{5}\s\w{3}\s\w{4}\b/);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you! Also wondering if say for example the block of text separated by white space was to include numbers and symbols how would this be represented?

Comment: @SuthanS `\w` already includes numbers.  If you want symbols too, then you need to tell us _which_ symbols you want to include.

Comment: These symbols not including the enclosing quotes "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?-=[]\;,./."

Comment: Then match a character class looking something like: `[\w~!@#$%^&*()+{}|:<>?=\[\]\;,./-]{4}`, e.g., for 4 characters matching numbers, letters, or one of your symbols.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate this as someone new to learning Regular Expressions.